# Replace string in command to be executed in zsh

Tags: command-line, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Say I have written the following command but haven't yet pressed enter to execute it:

```
$ ls dir1 dir2 dir3
```

Is there a way to replace given characters without manually changing them in every location they are? For example, I'd like to press some shortcut, enter string to be replaced (say, `dir`) and then enter another string as its replacement (say 'directory`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a `replace-string` autoloadable widget for that. Add to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
autoload replace-string
zle -N replace-string
zle -N replace-string-again
bindkey '\eg' replace-string-again
bindkey '\er' replace-string
```

Then press <kbd>Alt+r</kbd> to invoke. <kbd>Alt+g</kbd> to repeat the last substitution. See `info zsh replace-string` for details.